# polymorphic classes with pybind

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

i would like to wrap a polymorphic c++ class hierarchy to python using pybind.

My intention is that a python class inherits from a wrapped c++ class in python code and overwrite some functions. In my example below there is a python class Cat thats inherits from C++ class Animal and ovewrite function go(). This is working,  `print(test.call_go(c)` prints "meow! meow! meow!" as expected.

Python class Bello inherits from c++ class Dog and should overwrite function bark() and go(). But it doesn't work. Whether bark() nor go() are overwriten by class Bello.

`print(test.call_go(b))` prints "woof! woof! woof!". I expect "grrrr! grrrr! grrrr!"

and

`print(test.call_bark(b))`  prints "woof!". I expect "grrrr!"

It seems pybind inheration works only for one level of polymorphism. My naive expectation is that it works like or similar to CPP. I am only able to overwrite function from directly inherited classes.

I hope you can give me a hint to get it working or tell why it can't work. Thank you in advance.

I have tried the following modifications:

- use PyDog as trampoline instead of Animal -- `py::class_<Dog, PyDog>(m, "Dog")`

  - this result in an error by calling  print(test.call_go(d)) in python code, because d is not of type Animal anymore. I don't know why because PyDog inherits from Animal. Function bark() was overwitten as expected.
- in case python class Bello inherits from test.Animal instead of test.Dog then function go is overwritten as expected.

This is my cpp code:

```
class Animal {
public:
    virtual std::string go(int n_times) = 0;
    virtual std::string name() { return "unknown"; }
};
class Dog : public Animal {
public:
    std::string go(int n_times) override {
        std::string result;
        for (int i=0; i<n_times; ++i)
            result += bark() + " ";
        return result;
    }
    virtual std::string name() { return "Dog"; }
    virtual std::string bark() { return "woof!"; }
};

class PyAnimal : public Animal {
public:
    using Animal::Animal; // Inherit constructors
    std::string go(int n_times) override { PYBIND11_OVERLOAD_PURE(std::string, Animal, go, n_times); }
    std::string name() override { PYBIND11_OVERLOAD(std::string, Animal, name, ); }
};
class PyDog : public Dog {
public:
    using Dog::Dog; // Inherit constructors
    std::string go(int n_times) override { PYBIND11_OVERLOAD(std::string, Dog, go, n_times); }
    std::string name() override { PYBIND11_OVERLOAD(std::string, Dog, name, ); }
    std::string bark() override { PYBIND11_OVERLOAD(std::string, Dog, bark, ); }
};

std::string call_go(Animal *animal) {
    return animal->go(3);
}

std::string call_bark(Dog *dog) {
    return dog->bark();
}



PYBIND11_MODULE(_MyTest, m)
{
    py::class_<Animal, PyAnimal /* <--- trampoline*/>(m, "Animal")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("go", &Animal::go);

    py::class_<Dog, Animal>(m, "Dog")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("go", &Dog::go)
        .def("bark", &Dog::bark);

    m.def("call_go", &call_go);
    m.def("call_bark", &call_bark);
}
```

This is my python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from ATOM import _MyTest as test


def main(argv=None):
    print("check Dog")
    d = test.Dog()
    print(test.call_go(d))
    print(test.call_bark(d))

    class Cat(test.Animal):
        def go(self, n_times):
            return "meow! " * n_times

    print("check Cat")
    c = Cat()
    print(test.call_go(c))

    print("check Bello")
    class Bello(test.Dog):
        def go(self, n_times):
            return "grrrr! " * n_times

        def bark(self):
            return "grrrr! "

    b = Bello()
    print(test.call_go(b))
    print(test.call_bark(b))
    print(b.go(3))
    print(b.bark())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Did you ever discover the answer? I'm curious too